# How to receive a Cognito Custom Email Sender trigger event in Java AWS SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I tried writing a `customEmailSender` function in JavaScript and it seems the event contains a `code` parameter that contains either a verification code or a temporary password, depending on the `triggerSource`. A `customSmsSender` function would also contain a `code` parameter. But, I decided to go with Java to create my functions, and I am using version [3.11.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events/3.11.0) ([docs](https://javadoc.io/static/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events/3.10.0/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/package-summary.html)) of `aws-lambda-java-events`. Currently, my only option (that I know of) is to use `CognitoUserPoolCustomMessageEvent` as my event type.

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomEmailSenderHandler implements RequestHandler<CognitoUserPoolCustomMessageEvent, Void> {

  @Override
  public Void handleRequest(final CognitoUserPoolCustomMessageEvent cognitoEvent, final Context context) {
    log.info("Received CognitoUserPoolEvent {}", cognitoEvent);

    return null;
  }

}
```

The event gets logged with a `codeParameter` field that is null, but from the JavaScript example, I know mine contains a `code` field.

Also, the Cognito user pool contains a `customMessage` lambda trigger and I believe this is what the `CognitoUserPoolCustomMessageEvent` maps to. Every other trigger has an event type, except `customEmailSender` and `customSmsSender`. Is there a way to do this without just having to go back to Node functions for these 2?

Comment: I went back and looked at my code where I did the same thing, but without using the `aws-lambda-java-events` library, and you are correct, the parameter name should be `code` not `codeParameter`. This looks like a bug in the library. I think you will need to submit a bug report to that library, or just not use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find an `Event` class for both the `CustomEmailSender` and `CustomSmsSender` lambda functions, so I decided to just make my own. Based on the parameters shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html) for the custom message lambda trigger, `codeParameter` is correct, but it is not what I need since the [triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sender-triggers.html) that I am using, use `code` instead of `codeParameter`. I went off of the current `CognitoUserPoolCustomMessageEvent` class to create my own. Surprisingly, the event for both the custom sms sender and custom email sender are the same, the only thing that differentiates them is the `type` parameter.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CognitoUserPoolCustomSenderEvent extends CognitoUserPoolEvent {

  private Request request;

  @Builder(setterPrefix = "with")
  public CognitoUserPoolCustomSenderEvent(
    String version,
    String triggerSource,
    String region,
    String userPoolId,
    String userName,
    CallerContext callerContext,
    Request request
  ) {
    super(version, triggerSource, region, userPoolId, userName, callerContext);
    this.request = request;
  }

  @Data
  @EqualsAndHashCode(calSuper = true)
  @NoArgsConstructor
  public static class Request extends CognitoUserPoolEvent.Request {

    private String type;

    private Map<String, String> clientMetadata;

    private String code;

    @Builder(setterPrefix = "with")
    public Request(Map<String, String> userAttributes, String type, Map<String, String> clientMetadata, String code) {
      super(userAttributes);
      this.type = type;
      this.clientMetadata = clientMetadata;
      this.code = code;
    }

  }

}
```